# Always running Service with BroadcastReceiver for Call Tapping

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

### **My Requirment**

I am trying to build an application which shows a Toast whenever user makes a outgoing call from the phone. For this I am using a  BroadcastReceiver to tap the call action and a service (to run Receiver always). once I start this activity, it starts showing toast when a outgoing call get initiated ...everything works well.

### **Issues**

1. Sometimes I dont get any Toast Action **EVEN** for Outgoing call as well, is that mean service stops after some time ?
2. After phone reboot Toast Action for Outgoing call stops. Untill you start the servce again manually.
3. The code I have written is ok ? OR can it be improved ?

**Below is the complete code -**

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    CallNotifierService m_service;
    boolean isBound = false;

    private ServiceConnection m_serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) 
        {
            m_service = ((CallNotifierService.MyBinder)service).getService();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isBound = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallNotifierService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) 
        {
            m_service = null;
            isBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallNotifierService.class);
        bindService(intent, m_serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**CallNotifierService.class**

```
public class CallNotifierService extends Service 
{
    private final IBinder myBinder = new MyBinder();
    private static final String ACTION_OUTGOING_CALL = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    private static final String ACTION_ANSWER = "android.intent.action.ANSWER";
    private static final String ACTION_CALL = "android.intent.action.CALL";

    private CallBr br_call;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return myBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.br_call);
        Toast.makeText(CallNotifierService.this, "Receiver Un-Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_ANSWER);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_CALL);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_OUTGOING_CALL);
        this.br_call = new CallBr();
        this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);
        Toast.makeText(CallNotifierService.this, "onStartCommand Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder 
    {
        CallNotifierService getService() 
        {
            return CallNotifierService.this;
        }
    }

    public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        public CallBr() {}

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Action:"+intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alwaysrunningprocesswithcallanswertap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.alwaysrunningprocesswithcallanswertap.CallNotifierService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Could anyone please help for the issue OR pointout something better ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bharat Once device switch off automatically service will stop, So when ever your device reboot that time you need to start service again then only you will get Toast Action, refer this example code :

**BootCompleteReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.newbootservice;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;    

public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

@Override  
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

   Intent service = new Intent(context, AutostartService.class);  
   context.startService(service);   

        }  

    }
```

**AutostartService .java**

```
package com.example.newbootservice;

import android.app.Service;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.IBinder;   
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AutostartService extends Service {  


    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();    
    }  

    @Override  
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return Service.START_STICKY;  
    }  

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override  
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.newbootservice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AutostartService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newbootservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".AutostartService"/>

        <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">  
            <intent-filter>     
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            </intent-filter>  
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: do you have any idea about issue #1 ?

Comment: If you need to run at all times, look into a Service and startForeground. If you can let your Service die but get restarted, look into onStartCommand and START_STICKY.

Comment: *  If you can let your Service die but get restarted, look into onStartCommand and START_STICKY ==> I m already doing it. but its not getting started always ??.. is it conditional ?